# Is it subtable to using spring security to do authorization ( acl ) from cookie only?

Tags: java, cookies, spring-security, authorization, acl

I am developing a back-end application, but my application is only part of the whole project, there exists a cookies login application so that the authentication is done and not my control.

In this app, i have to design a file sharing system, some types of clients, file sharing between clients.

I can only get the cookie(custom logic and not standard) which contains all data i need.

My manager advices me to use spring security to do only authorization and then code the acl logic in the authorization. I doubt if it is a good idea.

i have read the spring security doc in brief, cant find any idea about my situation.

Finally sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

Its up to you. But I would suggest Spring Security.It is a flexible and powerful authentication and access control framework to secure Spring-based Java web application.

Comment: Yes, i know that, but if only need authorization?